# ReplaceAll with string builder with user input

Tags: java

I have a question regarding StringBuilder. I'm trying to write a program that takes the user input : for example "DOG DOG CAT DOG DOGCAT", then asks the user to input a word they would like to change and what they would like to change it to. It should then replace all occurrences and print the result.

I have a code:

```
public class ChangeSentence 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Write text: ");
        String text = sc.nextLine();
        StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder(text);
        System.out.println("Write which word would you like to change: ");
        String rep = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("For what do you want to change it: ");
        String change = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(Pattern.compile(x.toString()).matcher(rep).replaceAll(change));
    }

}
```

How should I change it to achieve the result?

Thanks!

**Forgot to mention, I need to use the StringBuilder (without it i know how to write it).

Comment: Result as described in the description. Takes 1st string "DOG DOG CAT DOG DOGCAT", user input "DOG" - user wants to change to " TEST" , so we get TEST TEST CAT TEST DOGCAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last line should be replaced by following:

```
System.out.println(text.replaceAll(rep, change));
```

It's simple. You have to excercise a little

Comment: replaceAll uses regex

Comment: @kwoskowicz. If you need StringBuilder:  `System.out.println(x.toString().replace(rep, change));`

Comment: or `System.out.println(x.toString().replaceAll(rep, change));` if both StringBuilder and replaceAll should be used like it is written in the title

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Write text: ");
    original = sc.nextLine();
    //StringBuilder x = new StringBuilder(text);
    System.out.println("Write which word would you like to change: ");
    String replacableWord = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println("For what do you want to change it: ");
    String newWord = sc.nextLine();
    String output = original.replace(replacableWord ,newWord);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

You just use the [function](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) `replace` on the original String and the

> first parameter is the target String

the

> second parameter is the replacement String